# Is there more lore on the Elemental Plane of Fire than what's in the Manual of the Planes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lore, planes

The information in the *Manual of the Planes* on the elemental plane of Fire is fairly minimal. Is there any more information available on the nature and character of the plane of Fire? I'm specifically interested in lore material compatible with the 3.5e-era model of the planes.

Comment: Reacting to a hold with a panicked delete is usually a bad idea. While it was safely on hold I considered the question and what its underlying purpose was, found a way to edit it to fit our question guidelines, and then reopened it. I noticed then that it had been deleted while I was editing it. For the meantime I've undeleted it in case you still want answers, but of course you're welcome to delete it again if you really want it to be deleted.

Comment: Not sure what the original question was, but I like the edits and now I'm curious to see the answers to this question.

Comment: @DMJohn You can always see previous versions of edited things by clicking on the timestamp of the latest edit. For this question, that would take you [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/71445/revisions).

Comment: @KRyan I did not know about that! Good to know!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll be wanting the 3rd Edition **Planar Handbook**, whose section on the City of Brass helps flesh out the Plane of Fire as well; the 2nd Edition sourcebook **The Inner Planes**; and the 2nd Edition Al-Qadim sourcebook **Secrets of the Lamp** (if you can find it). The 2nd Edition **Planescape Monstrous Compendium III** offers some notes on Fire wildlife such as the waiveras and scape, but the only new indigenous creature it introduces is the fire bat (other entries such as animentals, fundamentals and ruvoka pertain more broadly to all the Elemental Planes and may or may not be of use). If you want to poke around in it, the 2nd Edition **Mystara Monstrous Compendium** includes the helion and pyrophor, two more unusual denizens of the plane. Finally, there is a Planescape adventure (**The Eternal Boundary**) that takes a spin to the plane, but overall it's nothing you wouldn't get coverage of from other sources.

You may want to ask around on Planewalker for more information or check out the work they did on their 3.5 setting conversion; it includes a section detailing the Plane of Fire.

Comment: Is *Planescape Campaign Setting* *[Chapter 8](http://mimir.planewalker.com/pscs-chapter-8)* at Planewalker what you're thinking of?

Comment: Just a heads up: Secrets of the Lamp is available to buy in pdf format: http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/16877/ALQ4-Secrets-of-the-Lamp-2e

Comment: Chapter 8, yes.

Answer (score 11):

**Read The Planescape (AD&D 2e) sourcebook The Inner Planes.**

The 3.5e model of the Planes is based on Planescape, which is a popular setting published about during the AD&D 2e era of Dungeons & Dragons. The book in particular that you're looking for is The Inner Planes, containing information on both the Elemental Plane of Fire and the various Planes bordering it: the Paraelemental Planes of Magma and Smoke, the Quasilemental Planes of Radiance and Ash, and all places in said planes that have more fire in them. Do note that these books date back to AD&D 2e, so the rules presentend in them do not match D&D 3.5e one on one.

Also consider tracking down the **Monstrous Compendium Appendix III**, which contains quite a few monsters that live on or near the Elemental Plane of Fire.